# How to Create a new project by Choosing An Activity in Android V3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

Lastly I upgraded my Android Studio to latest version and while i going to create a new project it seems absolutely different interface came to create a project. many kind of varities are there but i dont how to choose and how to create a main activity. Please Show in screen shot of your answers. Please Help me

[image]

Comment: Please add more details like screenshot or anything helpful. What is exactly weird?

Comment: Did you config sdk directory in the settings?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path Or use `Configure` in the current window, then SDK manager

Comment: @Mohsen the older version i worked nicely and then the upgraded version makes me crazy. i dont think the sdk issue

Comment: Please add more details, then we can help you.

Comment: Please specify which step you have problem with

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago, I was faced the same issue.
Then I was performed those few steps.

If you use to create a project wtih Java then

- Go to android studio's **Settings > Plugins**
- Then unmarked the **Kotlin** option and click on apply.

My be it will helpful for you. Thanks