# Where is the directory of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I decided to move all of my android project from the previous laptop to the new one. But when i copy the directory of Android Studio & run it, it still need to download the SDK first. But because of various internet speed's problem, it is troublesome to re-download the various SDKs.

Please tell me every directory that must i copy to make it run perfectly? (without download any plugins/sdk/whatever)

Comment: You need to copy the directory of Android Studio and the SDK. It depends where you have these installed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path should help you find the sdk in case you forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\
```

on windows(username will be your customized username)

> /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk.

on mac(users will be your customized username)

Then point android studio at that sdk location and it should work