# Android Emulator Crashing After Moving SDK Folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I moved Android Studio SDK Folder to my D drive to save space. Here is how I did it: I installed and reinstalled making sure to change everything to point to my D drive, but there was no option to do this for SDK that I could find.

So I manually moved it by copying it over. I then changed the SDK folder in Android Studio settings from `File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure`. Then I installed an Emulator, but it crashed right as it launches. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered. You will find the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)

Comment: @Blaze_Mooney no, what I'm saying is I tried that, and it caused Emulator Crash

Comment: @bruhsmh try to create a new AVD with the new SDK path. And when it crashes, please provide the logs, in order to make this question less abstract; just run the AVD from a terminal prompt, in order to get some log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your android studio go to `Tools -> SDK Manager -> Edit sdk location button` and you can give your new sdk location here